# How to make Playground execution time is as fast as if we run in iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

I see that playground execution speed is not reliable. For example with a code:

```
import UIKit
var count = 0;

let startTime = NSDate()
for i in 1...10000 {
   count++
}
let endTime = NSDate()

let interval = endTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime)
```

[image]

the value of `interval` is about 2s, which is not reliable. 
With the release of Swift 2.0 & XCode beta 7, is it possible to make swift playground code execute as fast as in iOS application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a workaround thanks to the `Sources` folder of the Playground.

You can either use the menu to add external files:

> New > Add files to sources

or go to menu:

> View > Navigators > Show project navigator

and drop a `.swift` file in the `Sources` folder.

To be accessible, your code in this folder has to be public:

```
public class PlayGround {
    public class func count() {
        var count = 0
        for i in 1...10000 {
            count++
        }
    }
}
```

Then it's as usual in the Playground itself:

```
let startTime = NSDate()

PlayGround.count()

let endTime = NSDate()

let interval = endTime.timeIntervalSinceDate(startTime) // 0.0062
```