# Xcode Playground: new pages cannot refer to source files

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-playground, wwdc

I was very excited to view [the video on WWDC2015 Session 405](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/405/) Authoring Rich Playgrounds  , in that they seem to promise to reuse a piece of code in Sources, among different Pages.

However, it seems not happen automatically. I mean, a new page cannot aceess a func which is defined in a `Source swift file`.

What should I do to access func defined in a source file?

Thanks

Comment: @Sneha Thanks for editing!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30871264/2227743

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the function or class `public`.