# Swift is 1000's of times slower than C and Python code?

Tags: python, c, swift

I am new to swift, I usually work through some problems on project euler to familiarize myself with a new language.

Problem 7 is a good example so I will post my code for that one, I tried to write them all almost the same way...

Python....

```
def is_prime(x):
    div_by = [i for i in range(2, int(x ** 0.5) + 1)]
    for i in div_by:
        if x % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        return True

primes = 0
test = 2
while True:
    if is_prime(test):
        primes += 1
    if primes == 10001:
        break
    test += 1

print('the 10001st prime:', test)
print('finished in:', time.clock() - start_time, 'seconds')
```

Output:

```
('the 10001st prime:', 104743)
('finished in:', 1.8959460000000001, 'seconds')
```

C...

```
int is_prime(int num)
{
    int sqrtDiv = lround(sqrt(num));
    while (sqrtDiv > 1) {
        if (num % sqrtDiv == 0) {
            return(0);
        } else {
            sqrtDiv--;
        }
    }
    return(1);
}

int main () 
{
    clock_t start = clock();

    int primes = 0;
    int numbers = 2;
    while (primes < 10001) {
        if (is_prime(numbers)) {
            primes+= 1;
        }
        numbers += 1;
    }
    //Had to do -1 at the end because I added one to numbers after every loop, even when it found the last prime.
    printf("The 10,001st prime number is: %d\n", numbers - 1);


    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_elapsed_in_seconds = (end - start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Finished in %f seconds.\n", time_elapsed_in_seconds);
```

}

Output:

```
The 10,001st prime number is: 104743
Finished in 0.056207 seconds.
```

Swift...

```
public func is_prime(num:Int) -> Bool {
    let sq = sqrt(Double(num))

    for i in 2...Int(sq) + 1 {
        if num % i == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true

}

public func problem7() {
    var primes:Int = 1
    var next:Int = 3

    while primes < 10001 {
        if is_prime(next) {
            primes += 1
        }
        next += 1
    }
    print("THe 10,001st prime is: ", next - 1)
}
```

I didn't even time it, but uhhh its in the range of minutes...Why would it be so slow, is it just not meant to be doing this sort of thing? Am I doing something wrong or is this just what it's like?

Comment: First of all Swift is not constructed with the purpose of being used for HPC tasks, and apps using e.g. heavy video rendering tend to fall back on C libs. On the other hand, it shouldn't be as "extremely slow" as you describe, unless you're in a playground. Is the Swift implementation above "benchmarked" in a playground? For a fair(er) comparison, make sure to test your swift code in an actual project rather than a playground. Playgrounds can be notoriously slow, and are mainly intended for playing around with Swift, rather than benchmarking it.

Comment: Your Swift code completes in about 46 ms on my computer. By the way: your is_prime(2) returns false...

Comment: Did you test in the "Release" configuration?

Comment: Changing the Python block's `div_by = [i for i in range(2, int(x ** 0.5) + 1)]; for i in div_by: if x % i == 0:` to `for i in range(2, int(x ** 0.5) + 1): if not x % i:` improved execution time from 1.95 seconds down to 0.6 seconds. Based on that, I would guess that you're probably doing something wrong in the Swift version as well.

Comment: OP has commented under @hotpaw2's answer: `I am using it in a playground`. This is the main reason for the slowness in Swift. Code in Playgrounds *is* slow, you can't use this for measurements. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870978/how-to-make-playground-execution-time-is-as-fast-as-if-we-run-in-ios-application for a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift compiler assumes you don't care how slow the resulting code runs unless you request some compiler optimization, such as by setting a compiler flag, such as -Ofast

Otherwise the Swift compiler seems to add a metric ton of extra and slow machine code to the compiled result, possibly to help debugging.

Comment: But in general, my Swift micro-benchmarks seem to run at about the same performance level as my C equivalents under similar compiler (both llvm based) optimizations.

Comment: oh ok I am using it in a playground like the other commenter said. I'll have to play around with it more and see what I can do.

Comment: @deltaskelta Sigh... You can't make performance measurements in a Playground, this makes no sense. See this for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870978/how-to-make-playground-execution-time-is-as-fast-as-if-we-run-in-ios-application